Determining system clock frequency for a given sampling rate and number of channels
I am designing a multielectrode application on fpga. I am recording from multiple electrodes at a sampling rate of 2KHz. Lets say I want to create 60 channels for reading from 60 electrodes. My algorithm takes 1111 unit clock cycles to process a sample.
My calculations here are:
total sample rate = number of channels * sample rate = 60 * 2000 = 120000 samples per second.
system clock frequency = total sample rate * algorithm cycles per sample/ number of channels = (120,000 * 1111) / 60 = 2222000 = 2.22 MHz
Is this correct? I know there are other processes involved, adn this is not that straightforward, but I think this gives a rough estimation.

If processing a "sample" means processing all 60 readings, readings need to continue continuously such that all processing is done before the next sample arrives, and that processing takes 1111 clock cycles to process, then yes I agree with the OP's processing rate:
1111 clock cycles are needed within the time duration $T$ of each sample, with $T= 1/f_s$ where $f_s=2000$.
So we get $f= 1111/T = 1111f_s = 2.22e6 $ clock cycles/second.
Establishing required clock rates in an FPGA is a lot more complicated than this typically since in contrast to a processor, operations are done in parallel such that there is a trade in resources vs clock rate: Can the processing that takes 1111 samples be done such that some of those computations are done in parallel? Is the overall reading done over a fixed duration such that it is feasible to buffer or partially buffer with processing that continues after the last sample? Those are additional things to consider.

Thanks, @Dan, for the comment. Yes, I agree on that FPGA clocking is far more complicated. I am writing some reports and some analysis for my initial prototype, and I need to think of some aspects. I think of the processing units as single, isolated parts of my hardware. I believe in the future I could parallelize the whole thing by sharing elements in the processing unit, but I can't at the moment. Then I assume, each channel has a single PU, for that specific channel alone. I guess my napkin calculations are correct

Yes understood- I hope my answer to what you posted was helpful and complete
